# Check if they have selected a file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, uploadify, javascript-framework

I'm using the jQuery plugin, "uploadify" & what I'm trying to do is hide the upload button once the upload starts, however if they click it before selecting a file it still hides it anyway.

Here is my submit function:

```
$("#add_list").submit(function(){

    // Set new list id
    $("#filename").uploadifySettings('scriptData', { 'new_list_id': $('#new_list_id').val() });

    // Hide upload button
    $("#upload_button").hide();    

    // Trigger upload
    $("#filename").uploadifyUpload();

});
```

Is there a way I can get the value of the filename field? I've tried..

```
$("#filename").val()
```

..but that didn't work. Always blank even when selecting a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok..... So I decided to just update a hidden form field value with the 'onSelect' event; this way when they selected a file I can update the value to state they have selected a file; then check for this value before triggering the upload. If there is a problem with the upload or the user removes the file I updated the value to a blank value whenever the 'onCancel' event is triggered.

Here is the relevant code if it helps anyone else..

```
    'onComplete': function(event, ID, fileObj, response, data) {
        if (response != 'OK') {
            // Cancel upload
            $("#filename").uploadifyCancel(ID);               
            // Show upload button
            $("#upload_button").show();          
            // Output error message
            alert(response); 
        } else {
            // Submit secondary form on page
            document.finalize.submit();
        }
    },
    'onError': function(event,ID,fileObj,errorObj) {
        // Cancel upload
        $("#filename").uploadifyCancel(ID);
        // Format error msg
        var error_msg = errorObj.type + '. Error: '  + errorObj.info + '. File: ' + fileObj.name;
        alert(error_msg);
    },
    'onSelect': function(event,ID,fileObj) {
        // Update selected so we know they have selected a file
        $("#selected").val('yes');
    },
    'onCancel': function(event,ID,fileObj,data) {
        // Update selected so we know they have no file selected
        $("#selected").val('');
    }
});
$("#add_list").submit(function(){

    var selected = $("#selected").val();

    if (selected == 'yes') {

        // Set new list id
        $("#filename").uploadifySettings('scriptData', { 'new_list_id': $('#new_list_id').val() });

        // Hide upload button
        $("#upload_button").hide();    

        // Trigger upload
        $("#filename").uploadifyUpload();

    } else {

        alert('Please select a file to upload.');

    }

});
```

Comment: I know this post is almost three years old but thanks Brett. I find this really helpful in fact I used this method for a different issue I was having so I came up with my own version of your code to account for multiple file attachments.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this.

```
function submitForm()
                        {
                            var html = document.getElementById('file_uploadQueue').innerHTML;
                            if(html.length > 0)
                                {
$('#file_upload').uploadifyUpload($('.uploadifyQueueItem').last().attr('id').replace('file_upload',''));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                            alert('choose file to upload');
// or you can submit the form. If uplodify is optional for u
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But my "rubbish" answer worked just fine for me :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also call this php function via AJAX to find out if anything was uploaded. 
( I move the uploaded files to a set of folders after uploading, so this works for me pretty well ;) )

```
/*
     * returns the number of files in the tmp folder
     * @return number
    */
    public function countTmpFiles() 
    {

        $source = "path/to/your/foler"; //here are the uploaded files
        $files  = scandir( $source);
        $result = 0;
        foreach( $files as $file )
        {

            if ( in_array( $file, array( ".",".." ) ) ) 
            { 
                continue;
            }

            $result++;

        }
        return $result;
    }
```